# how to find row(s) in a matrix with different conditions on columns

Tags: matlab

I have an n-by-3 dimensional matrix (lets say `A`) and I want to find the row(s) where `A(:,1) > threshold1 && A(:,2) > threshold2 && A(:,3) > threshold3`. If there is no such row, it should return an empty row.

Comment: Please show your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with some example data:

```
n = 10;
rng(1); % Set seed to make example repeatable
A = rand(n,3);
thresh = [0.1 0.5 0.6];
```

Then, using [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html?refresh=true) we can apply each threshold to the corresponding column in `A` and [`all`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/all.html) to check if all columns of a row return `true` (`1`) or not:

```
B = all(bsxfun(@gt,A,thresh),2)
```

which returns a column vector of logicals

```
 0
 1
 0
 1
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
```

I'm not sure it makes sense to return an empty row in the case that your condition is not met, but if you want that:

```
B = all(bsxfun(@gt,A,thresh),2);
B(~B) = []
```

Comment: Or `B = all(bsxfun(@gt,A,thresh),2); result = A(B,:);` to return the _rows_ (not their index), including the empty case

Comment: I just want to know one more thing here.For example. if I have A(:,1)< threshold1 and A(:,2)>threshold2 and A(:,3)>threshold3. I can change the sign and use what you mentioned above but is there any alternative ? Thanks

Comment: @namanarora: Not directly. I might do something like `all([A(:,1)<thresh(1) bsxfun(@gt,A(:,2:3),thresh(2:3))],2)`, which is still readable code. If you're going to have mixed logical check, for just three columns it may make sense to do `all([A(:,1)<thresh(1) A(:,2)>thresh(2) A(:,3)==thresh(3)],2)`.